# how to insert a hidden field id in database using mysql

Tags: mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am passing the id in hidden field but while performing the insert query. It is not inserting into the database.

Here is my code.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " 
. DB_PREFIX .   "employee_details 
SET 

employee_id =   '" . $this->db->escape($data['empid']) . "',

        date = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date']) . "'
```

Here the `empid` is the hiddenfield id.

Comment: can anyone help me regarding this

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="empid" value="<?php echo $this->request->get['empid'];?>">    In view function i used like this iam getting the value but while insertion it is inserting as zero in database

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Does the net tab of the browser's developer tools show it being submitted? Does it have the value you expect? Does echoing it out from the PHP show it with the value you expect? Does echoing out the query give you the query you expect?

Comment: (And that's some horrible string concatenation; can't you use prepared statements? Or at least sprintf?)

Comment: What does your script say if you replace `$this->db->query` with `echo`? You should see your query.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.